# Find all prime triples $(a,b,c)$ such $a+1,b+1,c+1$ form a geometric sequence

Tags: number-theory, project-euler

Find all triples $(a,b,c)$ satisfying the following conditions:

(i)  $a,b,c$ are prime numbers, where $a<b<c<100$.

(ii) $a+1,b+1,c+1$ form a geometric sequence.

is from [mathematical Olympiad 2007 problem](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h543368p3137234),this links have found 11  triplets,
$$(2,5,11),(2,11,47),(5,11,23),(5,17,53),(7,23,71)$$
$$(a+1,b+1,c+1)=(8,12,18),(18,24,32),(18,42,98),(32,48,72),(72,84,98)$$

But How to prove why have  this 11 triplets ?maybe have other?

Comment: I can't get your question... "Why are those the only triplets?" Or "How did they find them?"

Comment: oh,I mean maybe have other

Comment: The second row is obviously not prime.

Comment: @Macavity I think the second row is formed by the values of $a+1$, $b+1$ and $c+1$.

Comment: @DanielEscudero  Yes, you are  right.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this than brute force. $100$ is a small number.

Comment: Even so, I count only ten triples..  Anyway, second the brute force argument.

Comment: Add $(11,23,47)$.

Comment: Add (7,11,17) .

Comment: http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/community/c3046h1184227_the_system_is_an_arithmetic_progression

Comment: It is also related to Project Euler problem 518.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for all triplets of prime numbers $(p,(p+1)k-1,(p+1)k^2-1
)$, with $k>1$ and $(p+1)k^2-1<100$  so $$1<k<\sqrt{\frac{101}{p+1}}$$

As $k$ is a rational number let 
$$k=\frac{a}{b}$$

$$b<a<b\sqrt{\frac{101}{p+1}}$$

And $b^2$ must divide $p+1$, so we can consider $b$ as the largest integer such that $b^2$ divides $p+1$ and find possible values of $a$.

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}
p&b&a\\\hline
2&1&2,3,4,5\\
3&2&3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\\
5&1&2,3,4\\
7&2& 3,4,5,6,7 \\
11&2&3,4,5\\
13&1&2\\
17&3&4,5,6,7\\
19,23&2&3,4\\
29,37,41,61,73&1&\\
31&4&5,6,7\\
43&2&3\\
47&4&5\\
53&3&4\\
 59,67,83&2&\\
 71&6&7\\
 79&4&\\
 89&3&\\
 97&7&\\
\end{array}
$$

So *only* 39 cases to try.

Comment: Are you assuming that $k$ is an integer? If so, what is the basis for that assumption? Many of the answers given have non-integral ratios.

Comment: @RoryDaulton I may have fixed the problem. But 39 cases it's not a few.